# How to release AudioContext in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, microsoft-edge, audiocontext

Is there any equivalent to [AudioContext.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/close) for Microsoft Edge? Is there any way to release an [AudioContext](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/apireference/interfaces/AudioContext/) or is this not necessary? In Google Chrome it stops the 'recording' indicator. How does it translate in Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "need" to release the AudioContext - it will happen as part of garbage collection.  The close() was to help more advanced scenarios.  In general, you can create an AudioContext and keep a reference to it until you don't need it anymore, then release the reference (e.g. "myAudioContext = null;") and it will get garbage collected in due course.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How about the red dot indicator? Is there such a thing in Edge? Can you turn it off like in Chrome?